# res.render() and res.redirect() behave like res.send()

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, fetch

I'm trying to use `fetch` for simple post request:

```
const headers = new Headers({
  Accept: 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
});

fetch('/checkout/billing', {
        headers,
        body,
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'POST',
      })
      .catch(console.error);
```

and the server side endpoint looks like:

```
if (!validateResult) {
        res.redirect('/checkout/shipping');
      } else {
        view.render('checkout/billing')
      }
```

So when I'm using regular HTML form submit it works fine (redirects or renders), but when I'm using `fetch` instead of redirecting or rendering I receive HTML body as response, like if I would use `res.send(html)`, any idea what can cause this issue?

Comment: What does your path `checkout/billing` resolve to ? If it is html then what you're getting is normal

Comment: in `view.render('checkout/billing')`? it's path to html template, but it shouldn't return me html as response, it should render that page

Comment: what you call _rendering a page_ is in fact sending html to a client (your browser) so that it can render. So yes it should return html. I'll try to clarify in an answer :)

Comment: ok I'll try to clarify my question) when I'm using html submit, it does what it should, send post request, receive html body and automatically render the page, or redirect to the page (if `res.redirect()`), but right now it's just send raw html as response

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** it should send you HTML *per spec*.

---

You expect JSON from your client, but you ask for a path that renders HTML, that is why you get HTML.

The word *render* may be a bit confusing: It comes from the idea that you have a template (that may be html / pug / mustache / ...) that your server will transform into html. But in the end, what the server does when you *render* is just sending the final HTML as a response to the request the client made.

So if the request is for a view in HTML, this will work as expected. But if you want to do an AJAX request, then you will have this odd behavior you are getting.

Comment: thanks for explanation, so what should I use instead of `Accept: 'application/json'`?

Comment: I don't know your whole application, if your goal is to redirect you could accept whatever, and redirect on callback of your request. Or if your application in a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), then you should send JSON from your server and handle your change in front-end with javascript.